# click on the link passing dropdownlist value to populate on clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

This opens url webpage but does not populate the dropdown list value.
    Contact

```
function shout(){
var selectval = 'I am select value to set';
var selectname = 'I am name of the select dropdown';
var url = "http://example.com/shout?selected=" +selectval;  
window.open(url);
}
```

Comment: makes no sense add more info and code

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to make some html elements

`<select id="select">`

`<option value="value1">Value1</option>`

`<option value="value2">Value2</option>`

`<option value="value3">Value3</option>`

`<option value="value4">Value4</option>`

`</select>`

Then add a javascript

`var s = document.getElementById("select");`

`var val = s.options[s.selectedIndex].value;`

`var url = "http://example.com/shout?selected=";`

`var newurl = url+val;`

`window.location = newurl;`

This is one method. Personally I would recommend php to use this the use the `$_GET and $_POST` and use a .htaccess to make the url not be like www.site.com/store/php?s=value1

Hope This helps.